# how to remove multiple token from string array in java by split along with [ ]

Tags: java

how to remove multiple token from string array in java by split along with [ ]

```
String Order_Menu_Name= [pohe-7, puri-3];
    String [] s2=Order_Menu_Name.split("-|,");
                int j = 0;
                //out.println("s2.length "+s2.length);
                while(j<s2.length){ }
```

and expected output should be each value separate.
e,g  pohe 7 puri 3

Comment: Show us expected input and output. Also, why are you splitting on `#` and `:`?

Comment: String Order_Menu_Name= [pohe-7, puri-3];
    String [] s2=Order_Menu_Name.split("-|,");
                int j = 0;
                //out.println("s2.length "+s2.length);
                while(j<s2.length){ }

Comment: Edit the question and put your code there.

Comment: also i want to remove [ and  ]..

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear. Assuming that your string contains `"pohe-7, puri-3"` you can split them using a `separator` such as "," or "-" or whitespace. See below.

```
String Order_Menu_Name= "[pohe-7, puri-3]";
```

To remove "[" and "]" from the above String. you can use Java's replace method as follow:

```
Order_Menu_Name = Order_Menu_Name.replace("[", "");
Order_Menu_Name = Order_Menu_Name.replace("]", "");
```

You can replace the above two lines with one using regex expression that matches [....] if you wish to.

After you removed the above characters then you can split your string as follow.

```
String[] chunks = Order_Menu_Name.split(","); 
i = 0; 
while(chunks.length) {
  System.out.println(chunks[i]); 
  i++; 
}
```

You can pass one or two params to the Java split() method, one being the regex expression that defines the pattern to be found and the second argument is limit, specifying how many chunks to return, see below:

```
public String[] split(String regex, int limit)

or

public String[] split(String regex)
```

For example

```
String Str = new String("Welcome-to-Stackoverflow.com");
for (String retval: Str.split("-", 3)){
    System.out.println(retval);
}
```

When splitting the above Str using seperator "-" you should get 3 chunks of strings as follow:

```
Welcome 
to 
Stackoverflow.com
```

If you pass the split function a limit of 2 instead of three then you get the following:

```
Welcome 
to-Stackoverflow.com
```

Notice above "to-Stckoverflow.com" is returned as is because we limited the chunks to 2.

Comment: thanks for attention...now output looks likes [pohe
7
 puri
3] and i want each value separate means want to delete [ and ] also bzos output showing braces [ and ]

Comment: Add these two lines before splitting the string >>                         Order_Menu_Name = Order_Menu_Name.replace("[", "");
Order_Menu_Name = Order_Menu_Name.replace("]", ""); see the answer, I have updated it.

Comment: thanks..,thanks.. thank you so much ..its all yours..issue get solved..have a nice day

Comment: Don't forget to mark the answer that helped you as accepted and vote up if you think is going to be useful for others.